Access Component variables from Outside - Vuejs
If I have a compount named <myCompount>, how do I access the ref or variables from the outside, meaning for example:
myCompount.vue :
<script setup>
import { ref } from "vue";
const myString = ref("hi string");
</script>

<template>
  <div>
    <p>{{ myString }}</p>
  </div>
</template>

myPage.vue
<script setup>

import myCompount from "./compounts/myCompount.vue";
import { ref, onMounted } from "vue";

const myCompountRef = ref();

onMounted(() => {
  console.log(myCompountRef.value.myString)
})
</script>

<template>
  <div>
  <myCompount ref="myCompountRef" />
  </div>
</template>


How do I do this with script setup:
myCompount.vue :
<template>
  <div>
    <p>{{ myString }}</p>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      myString: "hi string"
    }
  }
}
</script> 

myPage.vue
<template>
  <div>
  <myCompount ref="myCompountRef" />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import myCompount from "./compounts/myCompount.vue";
export default { 
  components: {
    myCompount
  },
  mounted() {
    console.log(this.$refs.myCompountRef.myString)
  }
}
</script>

Is it possible to do this in certain ways? I use Nuxt 3, but there is no problem. I just want to know how it works...

Thanks, I didn't know her

You could expose it using defineExpose macro :
<script setup>
import { ref } from "vue";
const myString = ref("hi string");

defineExpose({
  myString 
})
</script>

<template>
  <div>
    <p>{{ myString }}</p>
  </div>
</template>

